# What is the fastest way to get node title from nid?

Tags: 7, nodes, database, performance

Say I have an nid (or a lot of them). Would it be faster to load the node to access get the title, or do the very simple db_query required to get the node title?

Comment: Every answer talking to the database is incorrect as they skip the `load` hooks for example. Use `node_load_multiple` and hope someone enabled [entitycache](https://www.drupal.org/project/entitycache).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You said fastest.

If you can compromise two things, this should be the fastest one. Now, note that you have to compromise:

- If you are only trying to get the node `title`, and if you are sure that there are no other `hook_node_load` implementations (basically module handlers that would alter the node load at the time they are loaded), you can skip using the `node_load()` or `node_load_multiple()` functions and go for this solution.
- When loading a node from the database, it's advised that you use a query tag to make sure that the user has access to those nodes. If you don't use any node access modules, you can go down for this solution.

With both above points in mind you can uses something like this:

```
function MYMODULE_node_get_title_fast(array $nids) {
  $titles = &drupal_static(__FUNCTION__, array());
  $return = array();
  $unavailable = array();
  foreach ($nids as $nid) {
    // Lookup static cache of self.
    if (array_key_exists($nid, $titles)) {
      $return[$nid] = $titles[$nid];
    }
    else { // Set NULL, so unavailable nodes will have NULL as their return value.
      $unavailable[$nid] = NULL;
    }
  }

  if ($unavailable) {
    $results = db_query("SELECT nid, title FROM {node} WHERE nid IN (:nids)", array(':nids' => array_keys($unavailable)))->fetchAllKeyed(0, 1);
    if ($results) {
      $return = $results + $unavailable;
      $titles = $return + $titles;
    }
  }

  return $return;
}
```

You can pass an array of node IDs, and the above function will return their titles without the overhead of `node_load`, `field_attach`, or `entity_load` overheads. It also skips node access checks, so do not use this in sites that you want any sort of access restrictions.

Usage example:

```
 $titles = MYMODULE_node_get_title_fast(array(256, 258, 54898));
```

You would return an array, with all given array values as keys, and the title as their value. `NULL` if the node is unavailable.

Comment: Full disclosure: I have not tried this solution, but it answers the question the best.

Answer (score 5):

Use [node_load_multiple](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/node_load_multiple/7) to get nodes with your set of nids.

From the documentation page:

> This function should be used whenever you need to load more than one node from the database. Nodes are loaded into memory and will not require database access if loaded again during the same page request.

Comment: This is the only correct answer. If you need performance, enable [entitycache](https://www.drupal.org/project/entitycache).

Answer (score 3):

the better way to do this is:

```
      <?php
         $node_title = node_load($nid)->title;
    ?>
```

and i think that if there is a way to do it with out direct query to DB. then you must go to that way.as in most cases these ways are perfect,easy and optimized.

Answer (score 2):

Loading whole node data for just a title is overkill, if you apply entity_load() or node_load() it involved a bunch of joins to render the data from fields tables which obviously is not a good solution. I would rather suggest to apply 
`db_query("SELECT title from {node} where nid = :nid and status and status = :status" , array(':nid' => <Your nid>, ':status' => 1 ( //for published nodes)))`

Comment: That's kind of what I was thinking. However, I wonder, where is the breakeven point? How many other fields to join before its better to use node_load? or is node_load almost always just a convenience, and if you want to do queries for performance there is no harm in that?

Comment: if all you need is title then no joins involved but if you need some data fields which are attached through fields api then you will need that number of joins.

Comment: Wrong, you are skipping `load` hooks. Use `node_load_multiple`.

Answer (score 0):

The Easiest way to get it using [node_load](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_load/7) function.very simple and clean ;)

```
$node=node_load($nid);
// So $node->title contatile title
```

Learn this useful function.

> node_load($nid = NULL, $vid = NULL, $reset = FALSE)
>
> Loads a node object from the database. Parameters
>
> $nid: The node ID.
>
> $vid: The revision ID.
>
> $reset: Whether to reset the node_load_multiple cache.

**Also**  if you want get  [fetchField](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/DatabaseStatementInterface%3A%3AfetchField/7) by query use [db_select](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_select/7)

```
$result = db_select('node', 'n')
->fields('title')
->condition('nid', $nid,'=')
->condition('status', 0,'>')
->execute()
->fetchAssoc();
```

Also you can get it by [db_query](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_query/7)`

```
$result = db_query('SELECT n.nid, n.title, n.created
FROM {node} n WHERE n.nid = :nid', array(':uid' => $nid));
```

**But you can try it by yourself  speed test of getting one node with `db_select` `db_query`  is very tiny.**

> Use this function for SELECT queries if it is just a simple query string. If the caller or other modules need to change the query, use
> db_select() instead.

Comment: `db_select` is much slower than `db_query` (since we are in a performance question). Neither is appropriate. Also you recommended printing unescaped user data which is a *security hole*!

Comment: @chx printing was a example that he found title exist there,  also if you want fast way you can write raw Php  code!!! 
** printing unescaped user data which is a security hole** is not truth, title fetched from database , this thing you speak about is in writing in database not reading form it !!!!
and if you look at question and   comments you can see exact sentence about how speed performance.
and Finally I test it by myself, the different speed between getting node with node_load and db_query  is less than 0.001ms.

Comment: There are many modules in contrib that implement `node_load` hook, so depending on the modules you use, the difference can be different. I'm also agreeing with what chx mentioned about db_select vs db_query. db_select() is a lot slower, and I have found myself preferring db_query more and more.

Comment: @AyeshK ok, provide you benchmark here.

Comment: Cannot be checked with another function, or with a previous `db_query`if there are hooks affecting load? Is that stored somewhere besides the pure PHP code?

Comment: The `db_select functions class is in the select.inc in the database includes folder. `db_query` function and related classes reside in the `database.inc` that is included regardless. db_select needs one more file to include, and it also invokes tag-alter hooks, further slowing down. See https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!select.inc/function/SelectQuery%3A%3ApreExecute/7 for where the hooks are invoked.

Comment: Regarding printing an unescaped title, this is **absolutely** a security hole.  The title is user input that is saved directly in the database.  **All** user data rendered to output needs to be sanitized.  See https://www.drupal.org/node/28984

Answer (score 0):

Also if you want get it by query use db_select With [fetchField](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/DatabaseStatementInterface%3A%3AfetchField/7)

$result = db_select('node', 'n')

->fields('title')

->condition('nid', $nid,'=')

->condition('status', 0,'>')

->execute()

->fetchField();